# Double posting from wordpress to tumblr using curl/php

Tags: php, wordpress, api, curl, tumblr

Using a plugin in wordpress, I am attempting to pass the post info through the tumblr api to also post it to my tumblr blog.

Everything works apart from the fact I get a double post on the tumblr end, and I have no clue as to why.

```
function getImgSrc($postID)
{
        if ( $attachments = get_children( array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => array('image'),
        'numberposts' => 1,
        'post_status' => null,
        'post_parent' => $post->ID
        )));
        foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        $t_source = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID );
    }
    return $t_source;
}

//post blog to tumblr
function postBlogTumblr($postID)
{
   $URLServer = "http://www.tumblr.com/api/write";
    $t_post = get_post($postID);
    $tumblr_data = unserialize(get_option("tumblr"));
    $postdata['email'] = $tumblr_data['tumblr_login_email'];
    $postdata['password'] = $tumblr_data['tumblr_login_pass'];
    $postdata['type'] = "photo";
    $postdata['source'] = getImgSrc($postID);
    $postdata['caption'] = $t_post->post_title;
    $postdata['state'] = "published";
    $postdata = http_build_query($postdata);

    $result = datapost($URLServer,$postdata);  
}

function postBlogTumblr($postID)
{
    $URLServer = "http://www.tumblr.com/api/write";
    $t_post = get_post($postID);
    $tumblr_data = unserialize(get_option("tumblr"));
    $postdata['email'] = $tumblr_data['tumblr_login_email'];
    $postdata['password'] = $tumblr_data['tumblr_login_pass'];
    $postdata['type'] = "regular";
    $postdata['title'] = $t_post->post_title;
    $postdata['body'] = $t_post->post_content;
    $postdata['state'] = "published";
    $postdata = http_build_query($postdata);

    $result = datapost($URLServer,$postdata);

}
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is dedicated site for wordpress, take a look at wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: how and where do you call `postBlogTumblr()`?

Answer (score 0):

From your posted code, I can only suspect you're getting a double post because you've duplicated the function `postBlogTumblr()`.